# What are valid fields for the --format option of git for-each-ref?

Tags: git

I am trying to find the first branch that was created on a repository. To do so I used:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=commiterdate --format='%(commiterdate:short) %(refname:short)' --count=1
```

However I want more information on this branch. I.e how long this branch lived, when was it merged back to the master trunk etc. 
Is there a list of field options available somewhere? I tried googling a lot but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I've found a field list on git repository, [file builtin/for-each-ref.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.17.0/ref-filter.c#L328):

```
} valid_atom[] = {
    { "refname" },
    { "objecttype" },
    { "objectsize", FIELD_ULONG },
    { "objectname" },
    { "tree" },
    { "parent" },
    { "numparent", FIELD_ULONG },
    { "object" },
    { "type" },
    { "tag" },
    { "author" },
    { "authorname" },
    { "authoremail" },
    { "authordate", FIELD_TIME },
    { "committer" },
    { "committername" },
    { "committeremail" },
    { "committerdate", FIELD_TIME },
    { "tagger" },
    { "taggername" },
    { "taggeremail" },
    { "taggerdate", FIELD_TIME },
    { "creator" },
    { "creatordate", FIELD_TIME },
    { "subject" },
    { "body" },
    { "contents" },
    { "contents:subject" },
    { "contents:body" },
    { "contents:signature" },
    { "upstream" },
    { "symref" },
    { "flag" },
    { "HEAD" },
    { "color" },
};
```

Comment: Neither returns the tag name (i.e. `refs/tags/myTagName`) if I do `git for-each-ref refs/tags --format=... | grep` - why?! Without `--format`, the following is printed:  `HASH commit refs/tags/myTagName`. Git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0.

Comment: That github link is outdated. Here's a permanent link to where the valid_atoms are: https://github.com/git/git/blob/076c05393a047247ea723896289b48d6549ed7d0/ref-filter.c#L180

Comment: More permanent one :) https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/ref-filter.c

Comment: I know this is old, but it's outrageous that it's not in regular Git documentation and one must resort to finding it in raw code.

Comment: I suppose there's no way to extend this with user-defined fields?

Comment: Which one is the git commit SHA id?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 you want `objectname`
If listing tags it would be `%(*objectname:short)` - the * selects the ref the tag is pointing to rather than the ref of the tag itself.

Comment: @ingyhere These fields are documented in the man page (`man git-for-each-ref`). They're also available in the online docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Comment: `%(objectname)` is the commit hash and `%(subject)` is the commit message on HEAD.

Comment: Here's the documentation for date formatting in case anyone was looking: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---dateltformatgt

Answer (score 8):

[`git for-each-ref --format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt) mentions:

> A string that interpolates `%(fieldname)` from a ref being shown and the object it points at.

And it refers to the section "[FIELDS NAMES](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names)" which has a complete list.

Bit to see those options in action, you can report to [`t/t6300-for-each-ref.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c25fba986bfc737d775430d290b93136d390e067/t/t6300-for-each-ref.sh#L79-L216) which illustrates all the "atoms" used for `--format`.

Those atoms just evolved with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020): the "`--format=`" option to the "`for-each-ref`" command and friends learned a few more tricks, e.g. the "`:short`" suffix that applies to "`objectname`" now also can be used for "`parent`", "`tree`", etc.

See [commit 905f0a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/905f0a4e64bef35482a999dd01c64945b260c010), [commit 47d4676](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47d4676ac8a50b7d53e12ae200ed9b5661522129), [commit 26bc0aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26bc0aaf99147cdf2d29cb6d831dfa72ec94b61b), [commit 837adb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/837adb102f6bfd6e05c75afc630f20c1c720cc74), [commit 87d3beb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87d3beb6e0eedfb83a8dd425e3c612d977b6ac8d), [commit e7601eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7601eb55bdcd8b241c18e9d9b0106104f4515a1), [commit 5101100](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5101100dcc741694a1ca355c2e26e20daa348a28), [commit b82445d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b82445dc2789f2046831621e6be7b2af464af6e9) (21 Aug 2020) by [Hariom Verma (`harry-hov`)](https://github.com/harry-hov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c25fba9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c25fba986bfc737d775430d290b93136d390e067), 09 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26bc0aaf99147cdf2d29cb6d831dfa72ec94b61b): add `short` modifier to 'parent' atom
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Heba Waly</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hariom Verma</sup>

> Sometimes while using '`parent`' atom, user might want to see abbrev hash instead of full 40 character hash.
>
> Just like '`objectname`', it might be convenient for users to have the `:short` and `:short=<length>` option for printing '`parent`' hash.
>
> Let's introduce `short` option to '`parent`' atom.

And:

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/905f0a4e64bef35482a999dd01c64945b260c010): add `sanitize` option for 'subject' atom
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Heba Waly</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hariom Verma</sup>

> Currently, subject does not take any arguments. This commit introduce `sanitize` formatting option to 'subject' atom.
>
> `subject:sanitize` - print sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> %(subject): "the subject line" 
> %(subject:sanitize): "the-subject-line"
> ```

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/905f0a4e64bef35482a999dd01c64945b260c010/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L250-L252):

> Instead of `contents:subject`, field `subject` can also be used to > obtain same results. `:sanitize` can be appended to `subject` for subject line suitable for filename.

---

Git 2.33 (Q3 2021) exposes a new way to see that list: the code to handle the "`--format`" option in "`for-each-ref`" and friends made too many string comparisons on `%(atom)`s used in the format string.
That has been corrected by converting them into enum when the format string is parsed.

See [commit 1197f1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1197f1a46360d3ae96bd9c15908a3a6f8e562207), [commit 0caf20f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0caf20f22806dfd478ab3ac26b5f3682f383d3b4) (13 May 2021) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 289af16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/289af163002a314d5a38f007715d4b12c6ef28ff), 14 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1197f1a46360d3ae96bd9c15908a3a6f8e562207): introduce enum `atom_type`
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>

> In the original `ref-filter` design, it will copy the parsed atom's name and attributes to `used_atom[i].name` in the atom's parsing step, and use it again for string matching in the later specific ref attributes filling step.
> It use a lot of string matching to determine which atom we need.
>
> Introduce the enum "`atom_type`", each enum value is named as `ATOM_*`, which is the index of each corresponding `valid_atom` entry.
> In the first step of the atom parsing, `used_atom.atom_type` will record corresponding enum value from `valid_atom` entry index, and then in specific reference attribute filling step, only need to compare the value of the `used_atom[i].atom_type` to check the atom type.

You can see the full list in [`ref-filter.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1197f1a46360d3ae96bd9c15908a3a6f8e562207/ref-filter.c#L111-L159).

---

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) adds some clearer error messages produced by "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/78d15022e741b8f237b83d3f4bb8543674d9693d/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> and friends.

See [commit 285da43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/285da4321a9351d4c99dd1685a4aa2dfb47ff62e), [commit 1955ef1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1955ef10edf3c888dcb237728c81dd6e81df4960), [commit dda4fc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dda4fc1a849e2407c30b4619d64221c2b38bd570), [commit a33d0fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a33d0fae76ab95e88d383793cac41934920296ba), [commit afc1a94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afc1a946b256a54ba4abf530f0a720393aad461e) (14 Dec 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 78d1502](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78d15022e741b8f237b83d3f4bb8543674d9693d), 26 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/285da4321a9351d4c99dd1685a4aa2dfb47ff62e): convert email atom parser to use `err_bad_arg()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The error message for a bogus argument to `%(authoremail)`, etc, is:
>
> ```
> $ git for-each-ref --format='%(authoremail:foo)'
> fatal: unrecognized email option: foo
> ```
>
> Saying just "`email`" is a little vague; most of the other atom parsers would use the full name "`%(authoremail)`", but we can't do that here because the same function also handles `%(taggeremail)`, etc.
> Until recently, passing `atom->name` was a bad idea, because it erroneously included the arguments in the atom name.
> But since the previous commit taught `err_bad_arg()` to handle this, we can now do so and get:
>
> ```
> fatal: unrecognized %(authoremail) argument: foo
> ```
>
> which is consistent with other atoms.

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42b495e9c59f0634f535bbba074d6f75543235a5/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> and friends learn to apply mailmap to authorname and other fields.

See [commit a3d2e83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3d2e83a17d6ab9c50d14cfdff9f70a69de5c4c4), [commit 0144f0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0144f0de77edc96c6cd72ab9d50a68fc4c9c092e), [commit 04830eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04830eb762c83609a63805716daedb36014f6b6c) (25 Sep 2023) by [Kousik Sanagavarapu (`five-sh`)](https://github.com/five-sh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 42b495e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42b495e9c59f0634f535bbba074d6f75543235a5), 04 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3d2e83a17d6ab9c50d14cfdff9f70a69de5c4c4): add mailmap support
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kousik Sanagavarapu</sup>

> Add mailmap support to ref-filter formats which are similar in pretty.
> This support is such that the following pretty placeholders are equivalent to the new ref-filter atoms:
>
> ```
> %aN = authorname:mailmap
> %cN = committername:mailmap
>
> %aE = authoremail:mailmap
> %aL = authoremail:mailmap,localpart
> %cE = committeremail:mailmap
> %cL = committeremail:mailmap,localpart
> ```
>
> Additionally, mailmap can also be used with "`:trim`" option for email by doing something like "authoremail:mailmap,trim".
>
> The above also applies for the "tagger" atom, that is, "`taggername:mailmap`", "`taggeremail:mailmap`", "`taggeremail:mailmap,trim`" and "`taggername:mailmap,localpart`".
>
> The functionality of "`:trim`" and "`:localpart`" remains the same.
> That is, "`:trim`" gives the email, but without the angle brackets and "`:localpart`" gives the part of the email before the '`@`' character (if such a character is not found then we directly grab everything between the angle brackets).

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a3d2e83a17d6ab9c50d14cfdff9f70a69de5c4c4/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L306-L310):

> out of the trimmed email. In addition to these, the `:mailmap` option and the
> corresponding `:mailmap,trim` and `:mailmap,localpart` can be used (order does
> not matter) to get values of the name and email according to the `.mailmap` file
> or according to the file set in the `mailmap.file` or `mailmap.blob` configuration
> variable (see linkgit:gitmailmap[5]).

Comment: My copy of the git manual sadly does not refer to a section called "FIELD NAMES", so I had to search for this question to learn that the section exists.

Answer (score -3):

You want to use `git for-each-ref` so look at `git help for-each-ref`. Or [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html)

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Did you look at the section titled "FIELD NAMES" ?

Comment: Yes, and that list isnt exhaustive.

Comment: In the help there's nothing, and in the link you supplied, there's very little. Specifically, there's no exhaustive list of the available field names, nor of the "options" for formatting them (like :short). Specifically, I'm looking for date display options. I know about :relative, but I can't find nowhere the comprehensive list.

Comment: I'm not sure if this deserves a down vote. Maybe it seems snarky? In some sense it's a better answer since the help document should update when git does. Maybe it's not as complete as the chosen answer, but it's not a bad answer IMO.

Comment: Certainly didn't deserve 5 downvotes :/   Just edit it and pull in the relevant info from the link instead.

Comment: @MottiShneor FYI, the date formats are here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---dateltformatgt (as directly mentioned in the linked document of this answer)