# get the second most recent git tag

Tags: bash, git

I need the sha of the second most recent git tag. When running

```
git show-ref --tags
```

i get

```
ab295f707bc42e8975fd4d87142ca436c0fac94f refs/tags/initial-commit-tag
1c816fc0895faeecd48b9b31e09ba825698f92a6 refs/tags/production-2018-03-06-001
```

which shows my two tags i currently have. How can i get it to output just `ab295f707bc42e8975fd4d87142ca436c0fac94f`?

I tried `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1 --skip=1` but that apparently includes non tags as well, because when i run

`git rev-list --tags --max-count=30 --skip=1`

i get

```
d3d536c6745c823994b3fec8ce3b26caf2b4c6f5
08278f196cad30b5acbdd9d5f0baa58baab630bc
480513c6d94c6df52f49b91c5f90c39af4fc8f34
183a91321a85083fdf29b77bcbce5b9ca3932f12
e04e120be2f200bae88de37d1be2cebc8b07f74f
168b696f915adaea95c4e0d2a8cea68ea25538b2
0b9aa10a4f005f349e9553ac75552abc07723b95
befa7507836af93b1c765d957c65cbcf6ebea890
6850539077d82847907410d587ca3da047043915
a0a6d7b98c64ad318ff0d2c4252ac1ad94959bb2
3e91ed05db57b5dec23df0a465b9c8bc0a8dfe26
2341cf5a58974a9f57b0aa92a837e7857631f5cb
385a88d22c77cf26f21a906a2be65695528960b9
c7548f04d7b928eb7bf2f485aeb6fa78ef6846e9
a5abb21b1acb59617e3d69173d883c3e5f7db0f2
b0595fae8c8f697aa02dbd49d149da4f4efabad6
2c08455a1b86e1ba6de86844a83346262ab89e00
```

so there are not only tags in this list. How can i filter for just tags in here/make the first command workable to only show the second recent one?

Note: am on Mac/Linux, so bash piping would work as well.

EDIT:

In the end the `--no-walk` option wordked for me, so

```
git rev-list --tags --max-count=1 --skip=1 --no-walk
```

The accepted answer below is much more powerful though.

Comment: Look at the `--no-walk` option.  By default rev-list traces the entire ancestry of the tips on the command line, `--no-walk` uses just the given revs and does no further hunting.  edit: "most recent" can have many metrics, and for instance you can have multiple tags on a commit, so to get exactly what you want you're going to have to define it more clearly.

Comment: @jthill thanks a lot, that seems to do it!

Comment: What do you mean by '2nd most recent'?  When measuring 'recentness', do you mean the closest ancestor to a particular commit (eg the head of the current branch, or master), or do you mean the wall clock time of when the commit was made?

Comment: @WilliamPursell i only use this command when being on the latest tag. I now want to get the closest ancestor tag.  `--no-walk` combined with `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1 --skip=1` seems to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could refactor a bit your git command and pipe it to `sed` to extract the data you need :

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(objectname)' refs/tags | sed -n 2p
```

**Explanation:**

- `git for-each-ref` : [documentation link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref). Displays information about refs.

  - `--sort=-taggerdate` : reverse sort the output by tag date
  - `--format '%(objectname)'` : we only output the hash
  - `refs/tags`: we only list the tags in refs/tags
- `sed -n 2p`: output only the 2nd line

Note that if you don't have a `taggerdate` on your tags, you can use other sort options, like `creatordate` (full list of available fields [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256861/what-are-valid-git-fields-that-i-can-use-in-format-option)).

Comment: mh that wont work i am afraid. Prob is that i always need the second most recent (which is the second line counting from below), so if i would have 3 tags i would need `head -n 2` and so on if that makes sense

Comment: @JohannesMerz edited my solution to better suit your needs

Comment: thanks for all the effort you put in, it almost works, but...
- tags that are created on origin and not on my machine dont have `taggerdate` as property
- the `--no-walk` option from the commends under my question is much more elegant

Comment: Rather than trying to get the 2nd to last line with the tail|head pipe, it's (IMO) probably cleaner to reverse the sort with `--sort=-taggerdate` and pipe to `sed -n 2q` to print the 2nd line.  YMMV

Comment: @JohannesMerz if you don't have a `taggerdate`, you could use another option for sorting, like `creatordate` or `commitdate`. However, as you mentioned, if `--no-walk` works for you, then it is indeed simpler to work from there.

Comment: i will accept your answer anyway as its more generic and fits to more use cases.